# Conservation of a topological current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, symmetry

I am trying to prove the conservation of a topological current, as you can see in the picture. I show that the two of the three terms vanish. However, the last one doesn't. Any suggestions/hints?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the expression you wanna show is correct? I tried a quick evaluation with Mathematica by explicitly summing over the indices. The first two yield zero but the last one doesn't.

Comment: I have also my doubts because it is pretty obvious that the last term doesn't vanish. For sure, it is given that way but maybe there is a typo. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What confuses me is the mix of the epsilon tensor with 3 components and the covariant derivatives, which usually have four components.

Comment: Here we have basically a O(3) sigma model in 2+1 dimensions and with π^a*π^a=1, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the expression is not zero in general, it is zero only for $\pi^a\pi^a=1$. In that case you can express $\pi^a=\frac{\psi^a}{\psi^b\psi^b} $ for some $\psi\neq 0$. If you then do the math it will go to zero. This can also be checked with Mathematica.